# _swig_getattr AttributeError

Tags: python, swig, cgal, attributeerror, convex-hull

I'm getting an attribute error using swig to wrap a c function for use in python code.  I've got other functions alongside chap that work just fine, but some strange reason this one will not work :/

I'm trying to use CGAL to determine the Convex Hull of All Particles (chap).  Below is the chap function and the traceback:

```
std::vector<Vec2d> World::chap() const
{
    std::vector<Point_2> ch;
    std::vector<Point_2> points;
    std::vector<Vec2d> result;
    for(size_t i = 0, sz = particles.size(); i < sz; ++i)
    {
        points.push_back(Point_2(particles[i]->position.x, particles[i]->position.y));
    }
    CGAL::convex_hull_2(points.begin(), points.end(), std::back_inserter(ch));
    for(size_t i = 0, sz = ch.size(); i < sz; ++i)
    {
        result.push_back(Vec2d(ch[i].x(), ch[i].y()));
    }
    return result;
}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keiro.py", line 64, in <module>
    if scenario.run():
  File "/Users/marcstrauss/Desktop/keiro/scenario.py", line 56, in run
    dt = self.world.advance()
  File "/Users/marcstrauss/Desktop/keiro/world.py", line 87, in advance
    view.add_ch(self.chap())
  File "/Users/marcstrauss/Desktop/keiro/fast/physics.py", line 312, in <lambda>
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, World, name)
  File "/Users/marcstrauss/Desktop/keiro/fast/physics.py", line 34, in _swig_getattr
    raise AttributeError,name
AttributeError: chap
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the function public?  I got the same error when trying to call a function declared as Protected.  [The SWIG C++ manual](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn15) notes that Private and Protected functions will not be wrapped